# How can I get my Server (running on another Thread) to be active forever?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to write a basic Java client-server program, where in my client starts a thread which launches a Server, writes a number to an output stream, then has the Server read in the stream and print out that number.

My client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

public static void connect(int number) {

    String hostName = ""; // Enter local computer name here
    int portNumber = 4444;

    try ( 
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    ) {

        out.println(number);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know host!");
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IO Exception caught!");
        System.exit(1);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread t = new Thread(new Server());
    t.start();

    Integer[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    for (int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        connect(numbers[i]);
    }

}
}
```

My server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server implements Runnable {

    public void run() {

        int portNumber = 4444;
        boolean listening = true;

        try (
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        ) {

            String input = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(input);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port 4444");
            System.exit(-1);
        }   

    }

}
```

Right now, if I try to run my `Client` I get:

```
java Client
1
IO Exception caught!
```

I suspect that this is because my Server thread dies after it executes its `try` block. With my current code, I'd want my `Server` active for the length of my `Client`s for loop, but ideally I'd want my server to run forever, waiting for any changes to the input stream, and printing it out accordingly.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accepting only one connection on the server,  you need another try-catch to accept new incoming connections inside a loop, something like this:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {


    public void run() {

        int portNumber = 4444;
        boolean listening = true;

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber)) {

            while(true) {
                try (
                        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                ) {
                    String input = in.readLine();
                    System.out.println(input);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port 4444");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }

}
```